# PHP code to retrieve cover album via Spotify API

Tags: javascript, php

Good, again I ask your help, I'm working with Spotify API through a php `echo` in order to be able to retrieve the album cover.

To give an example of what I intend to https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=ADELE+HELLO&type=track,artist 
with this link gives me the information of the song ADELE - HELLO, I wish to retrieve this link was the next part.

```js
"images" : [ {
    "height" : 640,
    "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/071c7f412110d8754756e1833d978e5099a42648",
    "width" : 640
}
```

I've been to recreate a code in PHP to try to get what I want but without success. I leave the code to try to see my mistake or else if someone get a code to achieve what I want I'm grateful.

```html
$url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=ADELE+HELLO&type=track,artist";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:x.x.x) Gecko/20041107 Firefox/x.x");
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$get_json  = json_decode($output);
$cover     = $get_json->images[1];
echo $cover;
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: .... what? Your title doesn't match your question, what is it you are actually trying to do?

Comment: @Epodax 
I rebuild a php code and want it to remove the information is, the image link to this ("url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/071c7f412110d8754756e1833d978e5099a42648") but the dog has achieved Jameson solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from looking at the JSON in the page, `images` is not a direct child of the root (`$get_json` in your case), so it should be

```
 $get_json->tracks->items[0]->album->images[0]
```

try that

EDIT

I see you're trying to output the URL of the image, so it should actually be

```
 $get_json->tracks->items[0]->album->images[0]->url
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, through its information already get what I wanted. Good continuation

Comment: Where all here to help each other - best of luck!