# Extract Preview_Url through spotify API

Tags: javascript, java, php, echo, spotify

Well, I intend through the Spotify API to extract the function `preview_url` but I am not able to get to this function behind the code so I come to ask for your help.

```js
"preview_url" : "https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/5dcd99cf811094408dcfc1befe014495d786dab5",
```

```js
{
  "artists" : {
    "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=MAROON+5+ANIMALS&offset=0&limit=1&type=artist",
    "items" : [ ],
    "limit" : 1,
    "next" : null,
    "offset" : 0,
    "previous" : null,
    "total" : 0
  },
  "tracks" : {
    "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=MAROON+5+-+ANIMALS&offset=0&limit=1&type=track",
    "items" : [ {
      "album" : {
        "album_type" : "album",
        "artists" : [ {
          "external_urls" : {
            "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/artist/04gDigrS5kc9YWfZHwBETP"
          },
          "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/04gDigrS5kc9YWfZHwBETP",
          "id" : "04gDigrS5kc9YWfZHwBETP",
          "name" : "Maroon 5",
          "type" : "artist",
          "uri" : "spotify:artist:04gDigrS5kc9YWfZHwBETP"
        } ],
        "available_markets" : [ "CA", "MX", "US" ],
        "external_urls" : {
          "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/album/2Auw0pTT6EcQdvHNimhLQI"
        },
        "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/2Auw0pTT6EcQdvHNimhLQI",
        "id" : "2Auw0pTT6EcQdvHNimhLQI",
        "images" : [ {
          "height" : 640,
          "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/4c23a82f33b034795a0fbc67af559420c8cb4928",
          "width" : 640
        }, {
          "height" : 300,
          "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/44b0e6423240ed25f36f351ae043f68bb2ca3446",
          "width" : 300
        }, {
          "height" : 64,
          "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/2e8ff05c6f96006130bbc64ef0b42b402252ace8",
          "width" : 64
        } ],
        "name" : "V",
        "type" : "album",
        "uri" : "spotify:album:2Auw0pTT6EcQdvHNimhLQI"
      },
      "artists" : [ {
        "external_urls" : {
          "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/artist/04gDigrS5kc9YWfZHwBETP"
        },
        "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/04gDigrS5kc9YWfZHwBETP",
        "id" : "04gDigrS5kc9YWfZHwBETP",
        "name" : "Maroon 5",
        "type" : "artist",
        "uri" : "spotify:artist:04gDigrS5kc9YWfZHwBETP"
      } ],
      "available_markets" : [ "CA", "MX", "US" ],
      "disc_number" : 1,
      "duration_ms" : 231012,
      "explicit" : false,
      "external_ids" : {
        "isrc" : "USUM71409576"
      },
      "external_urls" : {
        "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/track/2bL2gyO6kBdLkNSkxXNh6x"
      },
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/2bL2gyO6kBdLkNSkxXNh6x",
      "id" : "2bL2gyO6kBdLkNSkxXNh6x",
      "name" : "Animals",
      "popularity" : 69,
      "preview_url" : "https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/5dcd99cf811094408dcfc1befe014495d786dab5",
      "track_number" : 2,
      "type" : "track",
      "uri" : "spotify:track:2bL2gyO6kBdLkNSkxXNh6x"
    } ],
    "limit" : 1,
    "next" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=MAROON+5+-+ANIMALS&offset=1&limit=1&type=track",
    "offset" : 0,
    "previous" : null,
    "total" : 99
  }
}
```

Code that allows me to reach the desired function

```js
$get_json->tracks->items[0]->artists[1]->external_urls->preview_url;
```

Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: What research have you done prior to posting your question? Did it turn up anything?

Comment: @OleV.V. I've been searching this site and I noticed this answer question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39913982/php-code-to-retrieve-cover-album-via-spotify-api) and tried to adapt to my question but without success or to remove the preview_url of the indicated function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you've got the correct path to the `preview_url` value. The actual path is `tracks->items[0]->preview_url`. Hope this helped in some way.

Comment: @Michaek Thelin Thank you Michael for the precious help you gave me to solve this problem and that's what I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: No prob - Happy it unblocked you!